# Show url inside a tab

Tags: php, jquery-tabs

This is probably a very easy question however I have been banging my head for the last week on how to solve this problem

I am using query tabs
In say tab 6 I have got a link to a php file. What I want to do is when tab 6 is opened display the url e.g. my folder/file.php?p=x&p=y&p=z .inside the tab.

I have tried the following:

```
<img scr="folder/file.php?p=x&p=y&p=z">
```

also

```
<a href="folder/file.php?p=x&p=y&p=z"<scr=""></a>
```

However noting will display
Is there anybody who can help?
thanks for looking

Comment: Is the file.php producing an image?

Comment: Thnks for your reply yes it is

Comment: Can you show the code in your file.php? Does it set the header?

Answer (score 1):

`<img scr="folder/file.php?p=x&p=y&p=z">`

Should be

`<img src="folder/file.php?p=x&p=y&p=z" />`

notice the typo in `scr/src` ^

Comment: sorry that didn't work. I think it might not be an image thinking about as when you put the ref on the image and then click on it, it will to you to a new tab in your browser. Sorry about that.

Comment: I suggest you look into https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/tabs/ajax.html a bit more as these are beginner problems with the component itself..